# How to remove ping program form alpine linux?

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

Silly question but still. For some reason I'd like to reuse **GID 999** and **UID 999** in my alpine Linux. Unfortunately, this id is associated with **ping** program in alpine Linux. How can I remove [ping](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/iputils) program, so I will reuse 999 GID?

**This is what I'm doing.**

Run my alpine linux.

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name demo  alpine ash
```

List last 3 groups from group file.

```
/ # tail -n3 /etc/group 
ping:x:999:
nogroup:x:65533:
nobody:x:65534:
```

Trying to delete ping program.

```
/ # apk del iputils
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.2c4ac24e.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.40a3604f.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: No such package: iputils
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delgroup` command to delete a specific group from Linux.

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

RUN delgroup ping &&\
        addgroup -S -g 999 exec && adduser -u 999 -SDHG exec exec &&\
        id exec
```

Build STDOUT

```
Step 2/2 : RUN delgroup ping &&         addgroup -S -g 999 exec && adduser -u 999 -SDHG exec exec &&            id exec
 ---> Running in d851c697c3c8
uid=999(exec) gid=999(exec) groups=999(exec),999(exec)
Removing intermediate container d851c697c3c8
 ---> 76a3ac4c1308
Successfully built 76a3ac4c1308
Successfully tagged ping:latest
```

Comment: That's what I needed. It's even simpler. Up vote from me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I arrived was simpler than I thought. I just removed line that contains id **999** from `/etc/group` file. Afterwards, I was able to reuse this id. I used `sed` program to do so below, is m solution.

Deleting, line of interest from `/etc/group/` file.

```
/ # sed -i.bak '/999/d;' /etc/group
```

Creating group named exec with GID 999 and adding user named exec with UID 999 to group named exec.

```
/ # addgroup -S -g 999 exec && adduser -u 999 -SDHG exec exec
```